Usability testing with Voice Controls
We are a team of 20+ currently working on an onboarding experience for an app. A significant majority of our target users will be using voice controls to navigate the experience. Normally our prototypes are built in Figma, but we use other software like Axure, Adobe XD, and Voiceflow when Figma's limitations come into play.
Wondering if anyone has experience with or insights on other software, plugins, etc. that can aid in voice-based usability testing our high fidelity prototypes.
Thanks.

The tools for designing AI conversations are limited or not well exploited. At one point, I had all my maps or blueprints on the Alexa app tool for mapping, which was great. However, I believe that developers and designers did not use it well, and the company took it away. Then, Voiceflow appeared, which helps you map all the conversations and identify the intents and utterances. However, when you need to implement images or wireframes, you have a huge gap compared with other tools. Then XD had a reasonable Design System for Alexa, and now XD is  Dead, and this one was the best to create prototypes and test them.
So, with time, I realized you need a combination of all those. Keep your conversation blueprints in a tool like Voiceflow to go on Figma and design the UI.
I found a Voiceflow plugin in Figma that helps you create WF, but it needs more work to be really useful. Its name is Voiceflow Transcript.
But if you want to test your conversational flow, the best thing I found is to create a skill in Alexa Conversations and test it in your Echo. 
Alexa Conversations Console
